# effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?

Tags: centos, sudo

I am using a cloud server of godaddy & I don't have root password. My master user has root access through sudo. I was trying to create another user and set permission for a specific directory. I've created a news user testuser & created a new directory named "test" under var/www/html/. I was trying to set permission:

```
chmod -R 0777 /var/www/html/test
```

but unfortunately i press enter before mentioning the directory. That means I just change the whole permission

```
chmod -R 0777 /
```

Now, unfortunately I don't have root password & sudo, su are not working anymore. changing permission is showing

```
Operation not permitted
```

and sudo is showing the following error:

```
"effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?"
```

I've several project live on the server. is there any way to restore the user permission. I don't want to reinstall the whole cent OS.

I've checked the `ls -l` and all permission are set to `drwxrwxrwx`

Please help me solve the problem.

Comment: Also look at the related and linked section on the right of the duplicate.

Comment: Ahhhh.....backups?

Answer (score 0):

The only practical solution is to restore from backups.

Answer (score 0):

If your `centos` allows passwordless root login in `Single User Mode/Rescue Mode/Emergency mode`, then you can use it to restore permissions.